# iOS: Over-The-Air installation - black download icon on retina iPad

Tags: ios, icons, distribution, retina-display

I've setup over-the-air distribution for our iOS enterprise App. It works, but during the download, the app icon displays black on iPad3 while on iPad1 the proper icon is shown.

I uploaded two icons, one in 57x57 pixels and one in 512x512 pixels.

Probably I need to provide retina icons too - but I do not see how to add them to the manifest.plist, as this file contains only two icon entries:

```
           <dict>
               <key>kind</key>
               <string>display-image</string>
               <key>needs-shine</key>
               <true/>
               <key>url</key>
               <string>http://myserver.com/image.57x57.png</string>
           </dict>
           <dict>
               <key>kind</key>
               <string>full-size-image</string>
               <key>needs-shine</key>
               <true/>
               <key>url</key>
               <string>http://myserver.com/image.512x512.png</string>
           </dict>
```

do I need to add retina entries? if so, what's the value for the 'kind' key?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, seems like the retina 114x114 icon is missing. You can try to set in the project directly under Targets -> Summary -> App Icons. Afterwards you have to create the ipa again.

Comment: This sounds right, Retina has twice as many pixels and `57 x 2 = 114`

Comment: i'm talking about the download icon for over-the-air distribution - not about the actual app icon (which is available to the device only once the ipa has downloaded completely). The icon that is displayed during over-the-air installation is not compiled into the ipa but loaded from the server where the ipa is downloaded from. It's referenced in the manifest.plist file (also on this server). but in the template file there are only two entries (labeled 'display-image' and 'full-size.-image'), which by all tutorials i found should be filled with a 57x57 and a 512x512 sized icon.

Answer (score 0):

Digging around a bit, it seems like the strings `full-size-image` and `display-image` are defined in
`System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iTunesStore.framework/Support/itunesstored`. And there're no other `-image` strings of interest.

Going on that, I'd guess you need to put two images onto your sever

- http://example.com/image.57x57.png
- http://example.com/image.57x57@2x.png

but leave your XML file as-is.