# Installing ios7 application twice from enterprise link but works fine when installed with itunes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7, device, xcode5

I have build the my app which was developed for 5.1 from xcode5 with the deployment target as 5.1 as i want my application to support ios 5 to ios 7.

When i add the application to the enterprise link  and when the application is installed in iOS 7 i see the application is being installed twice out of the two apps, one works fine but the other still says installing , I even cant delete the app which says installing . But if try to download the app from link again n while the installation process i was able to delete the unsuccessfully installed application.

Please suggest me how to resolve this issue of shadow app.

Should i change the build settings ? Or is it because of building the old app for ios7 but using deployment target as 5.1 !! I need to solve this problem as soon as possible.

I will be grateful if anyone helps me out.

Comment: The same thing is happening to me.

Answer (score 0):

A couple things that I have discovered with this.

First of all it seems to be less of an issue with iOS 7.1.
Secondly,  this can be prevented by making sure that the meta data in your manifest file is correct.  Make sure that you have the correct appID (com.yourCompany.yourApp) and it is nice to have an icon included too.  See here for what that looks like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13236395/ios-over-the-air-installation-black-download-icon-on-retina-ipad